# issue with string to datetime conversion in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, datetime

I have date as string in the format **16 Oct 2015 12:05:29:000** and I have it in **DateString** variable.

I am using the following line of code to convert it into date format.

```
Dim FormattedDate As Date = Date.ParseExact(DateString, "dd mmm yyyy HH:mm:ss.FFF", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

I am getting the following error.
    String was not recognized as a valid DateTime

what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is almost correct and just need to fix two things in existing  format string ie. `dd mmm yyyy HH:mm:ss.FFF`

1.) `dd mmm yyyy HH:mm:ss.FFF` -  here the format for Month name should be `MMM` because you want get `Oct`(`16 Oct 2015 12:05:29:000`)

2.) `12:05:29:000` is the time in your string but you're trying to parse it as `HH:mm:ss.FFF` <- (note : `:000` to `.FFF` will yields the error

and the final code should be

You've to use `dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss:FFF` instead of `dd mmm yyyy HH:mm:ss.FFF`

```
Dim FormattedDate As Date = Date.ParseExact(dateString, _
                                                    "dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss:FFF", _
                                                    System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

---

[`DEMO`](https://dotnetfiddle.net/jDVCTA)

Answer (score 1):

try with this

```
Dim datestring = "16 Oct 2015 12:05:29.000"
Dim FormattedDate As Date = Format(CDate(datestring), "dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss.FFF")
```

or as the same way you are trying

```
Dim datestring = "16 Oct 2015 12:05:29.000"
Dim FormattedDate As Date = Date.ParseExact(datestring, "dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss.FFF", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

you were using `mmm` instead of `MMM` for Three-letter month.please have a close look at the date string and format u specified.there is a difference which caused string not recogonized problem.